# How to center text on a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a text horizontal and vertically. Using de horizontal axis, I made:

```
text-align: center;
```

And it worked perfectly. But I want the text to be center on the vertical axis too. I've read lots of solutions, but everybody has different solutions and I'm a bit confused...

http://jsfiddle.net/QLPTD/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one thing you can do is

```
line-height: 25px;
```

You do not provide a height, but instead the height is automatically set.
You can try this, it works most of the time for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to work with % for different resolutions adaptation, so it doesn't fit exactly with my problem...

Answer (score 2):

CSS has a `vertical-align` property but using it can be a little tricky.

See [this page](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) for more info.

I have an outer div that has the `display: table;` property and then the inner table is `display: table-cell;`. I can then do `vertical-align: middle;` on the inner div. All of your styles are applied to the outer div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="menu_secciones" >
            Hello!
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    display: table;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10%;
}
#menu_secciones
{
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QLPTD/3/)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to align text vertically, you should use same line-height and height.

http://jsfiddle.net/QLPTD/7/

Comment: Except you changed the OP's height from % to px.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using padding to your advantage: http://jsfiddle.net/QLPTD/15/

As long as your padding-top and padding-bottom are they same and you have your display and height set accordingly, your text should appear to be vertically centered

Answer (score 0):

Line height is only a good solution if you are going to only have one line of text. The method **sachleen** mentioned is also another viable option. Another way you could do it is by using absolute positioning... For example....

```
<div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu massa nisi, pharetra elementum felis. Donec iaculis eros eu sapien pharetra tempor</p>
</div>


<style type="text/css">

  div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

p {
   display:block;
   width:300px;
   border:1px solid black;
   position:absolute;
   top:28%;
   text-align:center;
}

</style>
```

The top % would vary depending on your content.

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/gHXf7/